# Wordpress wp_mail with attachment (with meaningful names)

Tags: php, wordpress, email

How to use wp_mail function to send attachments with custom names for the attached files.

As of now email is getting delivered with attachment but name of files are same as physical file name.

I can't rename the files as we have lots of other references, but I want to send those files with some meaningful name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks QArea for your response. I found the place though, one need to edit the wp-includes/pluggable.php wp_mail function for processing attachment, It should look like this

```
    if ( !empty( $attachments ) ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $name => $attachment ) {
                    try {
                            $phpmailer->AddAttachment($attachment, $name);
                    } catch ( phpmailerException $e ) {
                            continue;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I am facing problem with woocommerce attachment i tried to customize plugin but i am not able sent the attachment in wp_mail Yuou have any idea how to do that. you can see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922249/wp-mail-attachment-not-working-dynamically#comment29647494_19922249

Comment: It's a **very bad idea** to modify WordPress source code. You will not be able to update WP unless you apply your patch to each update.

Comment: I agree with @A.Joahny, you should not edit wordpress core this way.

Comment: I've copied wp_mail() into a new function, modified it as described here and published it as a new plugin: https://github.com/gjedeer/custom-attachment-names-wp-mail/blob/master/custom-attachment-names-wp-mail.php

Answer (score 1):

wp_mail doesn't support rename the attachment when sending emails.
The one way to change names of sending files is copying this files with new names, attach new files to the email and delete this files after sending email.