# wp_mail attachment not working dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I have edited function send() to attach the file in woo commerce plugin when, I am use the attachment file path statically it work's but when, I put it on dynamically attachment source not able send the attachment but, I am getting mail.I am using select query for getting image from database to attach in mail.

```
function send( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ) {
 global $wpdb;

             $current_post1=$post->ID; 
    $result1=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT BgImageName FROM ca_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = $current_post1 ");

     foreach ( $result1 as $print1 )  
     echo $imgemail=$print1->BgImageName;


      //static path it's work
   //$attachments = array(  '/home2/rahulr/public_html/cutting-edge/wordpress_theme/user_templates/1384010402.png' );  

     //dynamic path it's not working
   $attachments = array('/home2/rahulr/public_html/cutting-edge/wordpress_theme/user_templates/'.$imgemail);


        add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', array( $this, 'get_from_address' ) );
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', array( $this, 'get_from_name' ) );
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', array( $this, 'get_content_type' ) );

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );

        remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from', array( $this, 'get_from_address' ) );
        remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', array( $this, 'get_from_name' ) );
        remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', array( $this, 'get_content_type' ) );
    }
```

Comment: can you show the printout of `$imgemail=$print1->BgImageName` ?

Comment: i cant print that because it process after paypal. but this same query i have used in other page its working i tried this with also session variable but not getting any thing.@ObmerkKronen

Comment: @SanjayNakate, did you find the solution? I have exactly the same problem and it is killing me.